# Generating display mockups (ex. for datasheets or documentation)

Tags: graphics, pstricks, documentation

I understand this is a very generic question but I have been trying to find something ready made to generate mock-ups of basic character displays (such as OLED screens) in LaTeX.

I have considered pstricks.

This is the kind of display I would like to generate mockups for:
https://learn.adafruit.com/monochrome-oled-breakouts

The main use case is documentation leaflets for small devices.

- Ideally I would like to be able to use a specific font size and even typeface mimicking the real one.
- Luatex/Xetex compatibility.

Comment: Do you have in mind only the black background and blue symbols? Mimicking a board may be difficult.

Comment: Only the display, inverted or write (inverted would be a bit trickier for printing, but nice to have). White background by default.

Comment: Meant white. Typo.